# Can one specify the default region for the EC2 command line tools using a variable?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

Is there an `EC2_*` environment variable to specify the default region of the EC2 command line tools in order to avoid specifying the `--region eu-west-1` option for each command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**for Latest AWS CLI:**

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
```

reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

**for older EC2 CLI:**

```
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Yes, RTFM. Thanks for the link to the latest version (AWS_DEFAULT_REGION). Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Of course this changes it for anything so if you only want it temporarily, you should change it back as soon as possible and serialize access.
Some sort of PUSH and POP would be nice, AWS people.